# Tailwind CSS: Cannot convert undefined or null to object & getProcessedPlugins is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css, autoprefixer

I'm developing a web app using Vue 3 with Tailwind CSS. My build failed and these 2 errors found.

[image: errors]

I've looked for answers and found https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/861 and https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2810. But both did not work for me. I tried to upgrade `npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest` and things were going even crazier.

I reverted it back but now I can't even run my development server and getting the same errors. Can anybody help?

This is my `package.json` now

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.5",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.6",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~2.0.6"
  }
}
```

and here is the `tailwind.config.js`

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  purge: { content: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.vue"] },
  presets: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: "640px",
      md: "772px",
      lg: "1024px",
      xl: "1280px",
      "2xl": "1536px",
    },
    colors: {
      transparent: "transparent",
      current: "currentColor",

      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.coolGray,
      red: colors.red,
      yellow: colors.amber,
      green: colors.emerald,
      blue: colors.blue,
      indigo: colors.indigo,
      purple: colors.violet,
      pink: colors.pink,
      linen: "#E0DEDA",
      "linen-dark": "#C9C3B7",
      "linen-darker": "#999181",
    },
    spacing: {
      px: "1px",
      0: "0px",
      0.5: "0.125rem",
      1: "0.25rem",
      1.5: "0.375rem",
      2: "0.5rem",
      2.5: "0.625rem",
      3: "0.75rem",
      3.5: "0.875rem",
      4: "1rem",
      5: "1.25rem",
      6: "1.5rem",
      7: "1.75rem",
      8: "2rem",
      9: "2.25rem",
      10: "2.5rem",
      11: "2.75rem",
      12: "3rem",
      14: "3.5rem",
      16: "4rem",
      20: "5rem",
      24: "6rem",
      28: "7rem",
      32: "8rem",
      36: "9rem",
      40: "10rem",
      44: "11rem",
      48: "12rem",
      52: "13rem",
      56: "14rem",
      60: "15rem",
      64: "16rem",
      72: "18rem",
      80: "20rem",
      96: "24rem",
    },
    animation: {
      none: "none",
      spin: "spin 1s linear infinite",
      ping: "ping 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite",
      pulse: "pulse 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) infinite",
      bounce: "bounce 1s infinite",
    },
    backgroundColor: (theme) => theme("colors"),
    backgroundImage: {
      none: "none",
      "gradient-to-t": "linear-gradient(to top, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      "gradient-to-tr":
        "linear-gradient(to top right, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      "gradient-to-r": "linear-gradient(to right, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      "gradient-to-br":
        "linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      "gradient-to-b": "linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      "gradient-to-bl":
        "linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      "gradient-to-l": "linear-gradient(to left, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      "gradient-to-tl":
        "linear-gradient(to top left, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      texture: "url('~@/some/path/to-an-image.png')",
    },
    backgroundOpacity: (theme) => theme("opacity"),
    backgroundPosition: {
      bottom: "bottom",
      center: "center",
      left: "left",
      "left-bottom": "left bottom",
      "left-top": "left top",
      right: "right",
      "right-bottom": "right bottom",
      "right-top": "right top",
      top: "top",
    },
    backgroundSize: {
      auto: "auto",
      cover: "cover",
      contain: "contain",
    },
    borderColor: (theme) => ({
      ...theme("colors"),
      DEFAULT: theme("colors.gray.200", "currentColor"),
    }),
    borderOpacity: (theme) => theme("opacity"),
    borderRadius: {
      none: "0px",
      sm: "0.125rem",
      DEFAULT: "0.25rem",
      md: "0.375rem",
      lg: "0.5rem",
      xl: "0.75rem",
      "2xl": "1rem",
      "3xl": "1.5rem",
      full: "9999px",
    },
    borderWidth: {
      DEFAULT: "1px",
      0: "0px",
      2: "2px",
      4: "4px",
      8: "8px",
    },
    boxShadow: {
      sm: "0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
      DEFAULT:
        "0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
      md:
        "0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
      lg:
        "0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
      xl:
        "0 20px 25px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)",
      "2xl": "0 25px 50px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
      inner: "inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
      none: "none",
    },
    container: {},
    cursor: {
      auto: "auto",
      default: "default",
      pointer: "pointer",
      wait: "wait",
      text: "text",
      move: "move",
      help: "help",
      "not-allowed": "not-allowed",
    },
    divideColor: (theme) => theme("borderColor"),
    divideOpacity: (theme) => theme("borderOpacity"),
    divideWidth: (theme) => theme("borderWidth"),
    fill: { current: "currentColor" },
    flex: {
      1: "1 1 0%",
      auto: "1 1 auto",
      initial: "0 1 auto",
      none: "none",
    },
    flexGrow: {
      0: "0",
      DEFAULT: "1",
    },
    flexShrink: {
      0: "0",
      DEFAULT: "1",
    },
    fontFamily: {
      sans: [
        "ui-sans-serif",
        "system-ui",
        "-apple-system",
        "BlinkMacSystemFont",
        '"Segoe UI"',
        "Roboto",
        '"Helvetica Neue"',
        "Arial",
        '"Noto Sans"',
        "sans-serif",
        '"Apple Color Emoji"',
        '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
        '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
        '"Noto Color Emoji"',
      ],
      serif: [
        "ui-serif",
        "Georgia",
        "Cambria",
        '"Times New Roman"',
        "Times",
        "serif",
      ],
      mono: [
        "ui-monospace",
        "SFMono-Regular",
        "Menlo",
        "Monaco",
        "Consolas",
        '"Liberation Mono"',
        '"Courier New"',
        "monospace",
      ],
      "cormorant-uprignt": ["Cormorant Upright", "serif"],
      "cormorant-sc": ["Cormorant SC", "serif"],
    },
    fontSize: {
      "2xs": ["0.5rem", { lineHeight: "0.7rem" }],
      xs: ["0.75rem", { lineHeight: "1rem" }],
      sm: ["0.875rem", { lineHeight: "1.25rem" }],
      base: ["1rem", { lineHeight: "1.5rem" }],
      lg: ["1.125rem", { lineHeight: "1.75rem" }],
      xl: ["1.25rem", { lineHeight: "1.75rem" }],
      "2xl": ["1.5rem", { lineHeight: "2rem" }],
      "3xl": ["1.875rem", { lineHeight: "2.25rem" }],
      "4xl": ["2.25rem", { lineHeight: "2.5rem" }],
      "5xl": ["3rem", { lineHeight: "1" }],
      "6xl": ["3.75rem", { lineHeight: "1" }],
      "7xl": ["4.5rem", { lineHeight: "1" }],
      "8xl": ["6rem", { lineHeight: "1" }],
      "9xl": ["8rem", { lineHeight: "1" }],
    },
    fontWeight: {
      thin: "100",
      extralight: "200",
      light: "300",
      normal: "400",
      medium: "500",
      semibold: "600",
      bold: "700",
      extrabold: "800",
      black: "900",
    },
    gap: (theme) => theme("spacing"),
    gradientColorStops: (theme) => theme("colors"),
    gridAutoColumns: {
      auto: "auto",
      min: "min-content",
      max: "max-content",
      fr: "minmax(0, 1fr)",
    },
    gridAutoRows: {
      auto: "auto",
      min: "min-content",
      max: "max-content",
      fr: "minmax(0, 1fr)",
    },
    gridColumn: {
      auto: "auto",
      "span-1": "span 1 / span 1",
      "span-2": "span 2 / span 2",
      "span-3": "span 3 / span 3",
      "span-4": "span 4 / span 4",
      "span-5": "span 5 / span 5",
      "span-6": "span 6 / span 6",
      "span-7": "span 7 / span 7",
      "span-8": "span 8 / span 8",
      "span-9": "span 9 / span 9",
      "span-10": "span 10 / span 10",
      "span-11": "span 11 / span 11",
      "span-12": "span 12 / span 12",
      "span-full": "1 / -1",
    },
    gridColumnEnd: {
      auto: "auto",
      1: "1",
      2: "2",
      3: "3",
      4: "4",
      5: "5",
      6: "6",
      7: "7",
      8: "8",
      9: "9",
      10: "10",
      11: "11",
      12: "12",
      13: "13",
    },
    gridColumnStart: {
      auto: "auto",
      1: "1",
      2: "2",
      3: "3",
      4: "4",
      5: "5",
      6: "6",
      7: "7",
      8: "8",
      9: "9",
      10: "10",
      11: "11",
      12: "12",
      13: "13",
    },
    gridRow: {
      auto: "auto",
      "span-1": "span 1 / span 1",
      "span-2": "span 2 / span 2",
      "span-3": "span 3 / span 3",
      "span-4": "span 4 / span 4",
      "span-5": "span 5 / span 5",
      "span-6": "span 6 / span 6",
      "span-full": "1 / -1",
    },
    gridRowStart: {
      auto: "auto",
      1: "1",
      2: "2",
      3: "3",
      4: "4",
      5: "5",
      6: "6",
      7: "7",
    },
    gridRowEnd: {
      auto: "auto",
      1: "1",
      2: "2",
      3: "3",
      4: "4",
      5: "5",
      6: "6",
      7: "7",
    },
    gridTemplateColumns: {
      none: "none",
      1: "repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      2: "repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      3: "repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      4: "repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      5: "repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      6: "repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      7: "repeat(7, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      8: "repeat(8, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      9: "repeat(9, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      10: "repeat(10, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      11: "repeat(11, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      12: "repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr))",
    },
    gridTemplateRows: {
      none: "none",
      1: "repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      2: "repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      3: "repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      4: "repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      5: "repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr))",
      6: "repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr))",
    },
    height: (theme) => ({
      auto: "auto",
      ...theme("spacing"),
      "1/2": "50%",
      "1/3": "33.333333%",
      "2/3": "66.666667%",
      "1/4": "25%",
      "2/4": "50%",
      "3/4": "75%",
      "1/5": "20%",
      "2/5": "40%",
      "3/5": "60%",
      "4/5": "80%",
      "1/6": "16.666667%",
      "2/6": "33.333333%",
      "3/6": "50%",
      "4/6": "66.666667%",
      "5/6": "83.333333%",
      full: "100%",
      screen: "100vh",
      "7/8-screen": "87.5vh",
      "3/4-screen": "75vh",
      "1/2-screen": "50vh",
      "1/3-screen": "33.333333vh",
      "1/4-screen": "25vh",
    }),
    inset: (theme, { negative }) => ({
      auto: "auto",
      ...theme("spacing"),
      ...negative(theme("spacing")),
      "1/2": "50%",
      "1/3": "33.333333%",
      "2/3": "66.666667%",
      "1/4": "25%",
      "2/4": "50%",
      "3/4": "75%",
      full: "100%",
      "-1/2": "-50%",
      "-1/3": "-33.333333%",
      "-2/3": "-66.666667%",
      "-1/4": "-25%",
      "-2/4": "-50%",
      "-3/4": "-75%",
      "-full": "-100%",
    }),
    keyframes: {
      spin: {
        to: {
          transform: "rotate(360deg)",
        },
      },
      ping: {
        "75%, 100%": {
          transform: "scale(2)",
          opacity: "0",
        },
      },
      pulse: {
        "50%": {
          opacity: ".5",
        },
      },
      bounce: {
        "0%, 100%": {
          transform: "translateY(-25%)",
          animationTimingFunction: "cubic-bezier(0.8,0,1,1)",
        },
        "50%": {
          transform: "none",
          animationTimingFunction: "cubic-bezier(0,0,0.2,1)",
        },
      },
    },
    letterSpacing: {
      tighter: "-0.05em",
      tight: "-0.025em",
      normal: "0em",
      wide: "0.025em",
      wider: "0.05em",
      widest: "0.1em",
    },
    lineHeight: {
      none: "1",
      tight: "1.25",
      snug: "1.375",
      normal: "1.5",
      relaxed: "1.625",
      loose: "2",
      3: ".75rem",
      4: "1rem",
      5: "1.25rem",
      6: "1.5rem",
      7: "1.75rem",
      8: "2rem",
      9: "2.25rem",
      10: "2.5rem",
    },
    listStyleType: {
      none: "none",
      disc: "disc",
      decimal: "decimal",
    },
    margin: (theme, { negative }) => ({
      auto: "auto",
      ...theme("spacing"),
      ...negative(theme("spacing")),
    }),
    maxHeight: (theme) => ({
      ...theme("spacing"),
      full: "100%",
      screen: "100vh",
    }),
    maxWidth: (theme, { breakpoints }) => ({
      none: "none",
      0: "0rem",
      xs: "20rem",
      sm: "24rem",
      md: "28rem",
      lg: "32rem",
      xl: "36rem",
      "2xl": "42rem",
      "3xl": "48rem",
      "4xl": "56rem",
      "5xl": "64rem",
      "6xl": "72rem",
      "7xl": "80rem",
      full: "100%",
      min: "min-content",
      max: "max-content",
      prose: "65ch",
      ...breakpoints(theme("screens")),
    }),
    minHeight: {
      0: "0px",
      full: "100%",
      screen: "100vh",
    },
    minWidth: {
      0: "0px",
      full: "100%",
      min: "min-content",
      max: "max-content",
    },
    objectPosition: {
      bottom: "bottom",
      center: "center",
      left: "left",
      "left-bottom": "left bottom",
      "left-top": "left top",
      right: "right",
      "right-bottom": "right bottom",
      "right-top": "right top",
      top: "top",
    },
    opacity: {
      0: "0",
      5: "0.05",
      10: "0.1",
      20: "0.2",
      25: "0.25",
      30: "0.3",
      40: "0.4",
      50: "0.5",
      60: "0.6",
      70: "0.7",
      75: "0.75",
      80: "0.8",
      90: "0.9",
      95: "0.95",
      100: "1",
    },
    order: {
      first: "-9999",
      last: "9999",
      none: "0",
      1: "1",
      2: "2",
      3: "3",
      4: "4",
      5: "5",
      6: "6",
      7: "7",
      8: "8",
      9: "9",
      10: "10",
      11: "11",
      12: "12",
    },
    outline: {
      none: ["2px solid transparent", "2px"],
      white: ["2px dotted white", "2px"],
      black: ["2px dotted black", "2px"],
    },
    padding: (theme) => theme("spacing"),
    placeholderColor: (theme) => theme("colors"),
    placeholderOpacity: (theme) => theme("opacity"),
    ringColor: (theme) => ({
      DEFAULT: theme("colors.blue.500", "#3b82f6"),
      ...theme("colors"),
    }),
    ringOffsetColor: (theme) => theme("colors"),
    ringOffsetWidth: {
      0: "0px",
      1: "1px",
      2: "2px",
      4: "4px",
      8: "8px",
    },
    ringOpacity: (theme) => ({
      DEFAULT: "0.5",
      ...theme("opacity"),
    }),
    ringWidth: {
      DEFAULT: "3px",
      0: "0px",
      1: "1px",
      2: "2px",
      4: "4px",
      8: "8px",
    },
    rotate: {
      "-180": "-180deg",
      "-90": "-90deg",
      "-45": "-45deg",
      "-12": "-12deg",
      "-6": "-6deg",
      "-3": "-3deg",
      "-2": "-2deg",
      "-1": "-1deg",
      0: "0deg",
      1: "1deg",
      2: "2deg",
      3: "3deg",
      6: "6deg",
      12: "12deg",
      45: "45deg",
      90: "90deg",
      180: "180deg",
    },
    scale: {
      0: "0",
      50: ".5",
      75: ".75",
      90: ".9",
      95: ".95",
      100: "1",
      105: "1.05",
      110: "1.1",
      125: "1.25",
      150: "1.5",
    },
    skew: {
      "-12": "-12deg",
      "-6": "-6deg",
      "-3": "-3deg",
      "-2": "-2deg",
      "-1": "-1deg",
      0: "0deg",
      1: "1deg",
      2: "2deg",
      3: "3deg",
      6: "6deg",
      12: "12deg",
    },
    space: (theme, { negative }) => ({
      ...theme("spacing"),
      ...negative(theme("spacing")),
    }),
    stroke: {
      current: "currentColor",
    },
    strokeWidth: {
      0: "0",
      1: "1",
      2: "2",
    },
    textColor: (theme) => theme("colors"),
    textOpacity: (theme) => theme("opacity"),
    transformOrigin: {
      center: "center",
      top: "top",
      "top-right": "top right",
      right: "right",
      "bottom-right": "bottom right",
      bottom: "bottom",
      "bottom-left": "bottom left",
      left: "left",
      "top-left": "top left",
    },
    transitionDelay: {
      75: "75ms",
      100: "100ms",
      150: "150ms",
      200: "200ms",
      300: "300ms",
      500: "500ms",
      700: "700ms",
      1000: "1000ms",
    },
    transitionDuration: {
      DEFAULT: "150ms",
      75: "75ms",
      100: "100ms",
      150: "150ms",
      200: "200ms",
      300: "300ms",
      500: "500ms",
      700: "700ms",
      1000: "1000ms",
    },
    transitionProperty: {
      none: "none",
      all: "all",
      DEFAULT:
        "background-color, border-color, color, fill, stroke, opacity, box-shadow, transform",
      colors: "background-color, border-color, color, fill, stroke",
      opacity: "opacity",
      shadow: "box-shadow",
      transform: "transform",
    },
    transitionTimingFunction: {
      DEFAULT: "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)",
      linear: "linear",
      in: "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1)",
      out: "cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1)",
      "in-out": "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)",
    },
    translate: (theme, { negative }) => ({
      ...theme("spacing"),
      ...negative(theme("spacing")),
      "1/2": "50%",
      "1/3": "33.333333%",
      "2/3": "66.666667%",
      "1/4": "25%",
      "2/4": "50%",
      "3/4": "75%",
      full: "100%",
      "-1/2": "-50%",
      "-1/3": "-33.333333%",
      "-2/3": "-66.666667%",
      "-1/4": "-25%",
      "-2/4": "-50%",
      "-3/4": "-75%",
      "-full": "-100%",
    }),
    width: (theme) => ({
      auto: "auto",
      ...theme("spacing"),
      "1/2": "50%",
      "1/3": "33.333333%",
      "2/3": "66.666667%",
      "1/4": "25%",
      "2/4": "50%",
      "3/4": "75%",
      "1/5": "20%",
      "2/5": "40%",
      "3/5": "60%",
      "4/5": "80%",
      "1/6": "16.666667%",
      "2/6": "33.333333%",
      "3/6": "50%",
      "4/6": "66.666667%",
      "5/6": "83.333333%",
      "1/12": "8.333333%",
      "2/12": "16.666667%",
      "3/12": "25%",
      "4/12": "33.333333%",
      "5/12": "41.666667%",
      "6/12": "50%",
      "7/12": "58.333333%",
      "8/12": "66.666667%",
      "9/12": "75%",
      "10/12": "83.333333%",
      "11/12": "91.666667%",
      full: "100%",
      screen: "100vw",
      "3/4-screen": "75vw",
      "1/2-screen": "50vw",
      "1/3-screen": "33.333333vw",
      "1/4-screen": "25vw",
      min: "min-content",
      max: "max-content",
    }),
    zIndex: {
      auto: "auto",
      0: "0",
      10: "10",
      20: "20",
      30: "30",
      40: "40",
      50: "50",
    },
  },
  variantOrder: [
    "first",
    "last",
    "odd",
    "even",
    "visited",
    "checked",
    "group-hover",
    "group-focus",
    "focus-within",
    "hover",
    "focus",
    "focus-visible",
    "active",
    "disabled",
  ],
  variants: {
    accessibility: ["responsive", "focus-within", "focus"],
    alignContent: ["responsive"],
    alignItems: ["responsive"],
    alignSelf: ["responsive"],
    animation: ["responsive", "hover"],
    appearance: ["responsive"],
    backgroundAttachment: ["responsive"],
    backgroundClip: ["responsive"],
    backgroundColor: [
      "responsive",
      "dark",
      "group-hover",
      "focus-within",
      "hover",
      "focus",
    ],
    backgroundImage: ["responsive"],
    backgroundOpacity: [
      "responsive",
      "dark",
      "group-hover",
      "focus-within",
      "hover",
      "focus",
    ],
    backgroundPosition: ["responsive"],
    backgroundRepeat: ["responsive"],
    backgroundSize: ["responsive"],
    borderCollapse: ["responsive"],
    borderColor: [
      "responsive",
      "dark",
      "group-hover",
      "focus-within",
      "hover",
      "focus",
    ],
    borderOpacity: [
      "responsive",
      "dark",
      "group-hover",
      "focus-within",
      "hover",
      "focus",
    ],
    borderRadius: ["responsive"],
    borderStyle: ["responsive"],
    borderWidth: ["responsive", "focus"],
    boxShadow: ["responsive", "group-hover", "focus-within", "hover", "focus"],
    boxSizing: ["responsive"],
    clear: ["responsive"],
    container: ["responsive"],
    cursor: ["responsive"],
    display: ["responsive"],
    divideColor: ["responsive", "dark"],
    divideOpacity: ["responsive", "dark"],
    divideStyle: ["responsive"],
    divideWidth: ["responsive"],
    fill: ["responsive"],
    flex: ["responsive"],
    flexDirection: ["responsive"],
    flexGrow: ["responsive"],
    flexShrink: ["responsive"],
    flexWrap: ["responsive"],
    float: ["responsive"],
    fontFamily: ["responsive"],
    fontSize: ["responsive"],
    fontSmoothing: ["responsive"],
    fontStyle: ["responsive"],
    fontVariantNumeric: ["responsive"],
    fontWeight: ["responsive"],
    gap: ["responsive"],
    gradientColorStops: ["responsive", "dark", "hover", "focus"],
    gridAutoColumns: ["responsive"],
    gridAutoFlow: ["responsive"],
    gridAutoRows: ["responsive"],
    gridColumn: ["responsive"],
    gridColumnEnd: ["responsive"],
    gridColumnStart: ["responsive"],
    gridRow: ["responsive"],
    gridRowEnd: ["responsive"],
    gridRowStart: ["responsive"],
    gridTemplateColumns: ["responsive"],
    gridTemplateRows: ["responsive"],
    height: ["responsive"],
    inset: ["responsive"],
    justifyContent: ["responsive"],
    justifyItems: ["responsive"],
    justifySelf: ["responsive"],
    letterSpacing: ["responsive"],
    lineHeight: ["responsive"],
    listStylePosition: ["responsive"],
    listStyleType: ["responsive"],
    margin: ["responsive"],
    maxHeight: ["responsive"],
    maxWidth: ["responsive"],
    minHeight: ["responsive"],
    minWidth: ["responsive"],
    objectFit: ["responsive"],
    objectPosition: ["responsive"],
    opacity: ["responsive", "group-hover", "focus-within", "hover", "focus"],
    order: ["responsive"],
    outline: ["responsive", "focus-within", "focus"],
    overflow: ["responsive", "hover"],
    overscrollBehavior: ["responsive"],
    padding: ["responsive"],
    placeContent: ["responsive"],
    placeItems: ["responsive"],
    placeSelf: ["responsive"],
    placeholderColor: ["responsive", "dark", "focus"],
    placeholderOpacity: ["responsive", "dark", "focus"],
    pointerEvents: ["responsive"],
    position: ["responsive"],
    resize: ["responsive"],
    ringColor: ["responsive", "dark", "focus-within", "focus"],
    ringOffsetColor: ["responsive", "dark", "focus-within", "focus"],
    ringOffsetWidth: ["responsive", "focus-within", "focus"],
    ringOpacity: ["responsive", "dark", "focus-within", "focus"],
    ringWidth: ["responsive", "focus-within", "focus"],
    rotate: ["responsive", "hover", "focus"],
    scale: ["responsive", "hover", "focus"],
    skew: ["responsive", "hover", "focus"],
    space: ["responsive"],
    stroke: ["responsive"],
    strokeWidth: ["responsive"],
    tableLayout: ["responsive"],
    textAlign: ["responsive"],
    textColor: [
      "responsive",
      "dark",
      "group-hover",
      "focus-within",
      "hover",
      "focus",
    ],
    textDecoration: [
      "responsive",
      "group-hover",
      "focus-within",
      "hover",
      "focus",
    ],
    textOpacity: [
      "responsive",
      "dark",
      "group-hover",
      "focus-within",
      "hover",
      "focus",
    ],
    textOverflow: ["responsive"],
    textTransform: ["responsive"],
    transform: ["responsive"],
    transformOrigin: ["responsive"],
    transitionDelay: ["responsive"],
    transitionDuration: ["responsive"],
    transitionProperty: ["responsive"],
    transitionTimingFunction: ["responsive"],
    translate: ["responsive", "hover", "focus"],
    userSelect: ["responsive"],
    verticalAlign: ["responsive"],
    visibility: ["responsive"],
    whitespace: ["responsive"],
    width: ["responsive"],
    wordBreak: ["responsive"],
    zIndex: ["responsive", "focus-within", "focus"],
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Do you have a `tailwind.config.js` file?

Comment: I do, I'll add it to the question

Comment: Try removing the config file, do you still get the error?

Comment: Well no, but now my self-defined utilities are gone. And I'm pretty sure it causes these new errors saying that `bg-linen class does not exist, but bg-none does. If you're sure that bg-linen exists, make sure that any @import statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as @apply can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.` :(

Comment: OK, but it's very possible that something in the config is causing the error, I would try to remove all the custom utilities, then adding them back chunk by chunk, then check when the first error is showing up again, so you will now where the problem is.

Comment: Also, which version of Tailwind do you use? if >2 check out [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build).

Comment: Ah okay thanks, I'll try removing then adding them chunk by chunk first

Comment: Hi, @ShayaUlman I just wanna let you know that I ended up recreating the project by following this guide https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vue-3-vite

Answer (score 10):

Removing `presets: [],` from `tailwind.config.js` fixed it for me.

Comment: Using `"sass": "^1.42.1"`, `"sass-loader":"^10.2.0"`,`"postcss":"^8.3.9"`,`"@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1"` this was also the solution for me.. Wow.
If anyone could explain that would be great.

Comment: I had a similar issue, removing the empty object `variants: { extend: {} }` fixed it for me